# mocha import external script failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have this opcode.js file and need to test it with mocha.An example can be seen here :

```
var opcode = {
    '0': {
        decode: function (data) {
            var ocBuf = new OpcodeBuffer(data);
            var kpo = {};
            kpo.opcode = 0x00;
            ocBuf.setIndex(1);
            kpo.sid = ocBuf.readUInt16();
            return kpo;
        },
        encode: function (kpo) {
            var ocBuf = new OpcodeBuffer(opcode['0'].encodeLength(kpo));
            ocBuf.writeUInt8(0x00);
            ocBuf.writeUInt16(kpo.sid);
            return ocBuf.buf;
        }
module.exports = opcode;
```

and the write in my test_ack.js file:

```
var op = require('./ack.js');
var assert = require('assert');
opcode = op.opcode;
var decode = require('opcode').decode();
var encode = require('opcode').encode();
```

the problem is that i keep having this encode and decode not defined error messages.I still cannot get how can i import them in my directory.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you show us, this would be the way you could import your two functions:

```
var decode = require('opcode')["0"].decode;
var encode = require('opcode')["0"].encode;
```

I'd suggest additionally avoiding calling `require` twice. Among other things, the code you currently have *calls* the functions instead of just importing them.